# can GLSL datatypes be used for generic vector/matrix calculation in OpenGL programs?

Tags: opengl, glsl

not sure if it's a good idea to use GLSL datatypes and functions for vector and matrix calculations even though I don't intend to use GLSL in my program. GLSL is something that comes with OpenGL, so I don't need to make my own simple vector/matrix class or borrow from another libaray to do this, but I don't know enough about its usability with generic OpenGL operations.

how do you use GLSL? do you just include gl.h and get access to vec3 and cross functions? do I need to use write down the class name for dot,cross, and the functions? (like std::vector, do I need gl::cross every time I call these functions?)

are GLSO datatypes compatible with basic OpenGL functions like glColor, glVertex, and glTranslate?

I have seen GLSL equivalent of glVertex3f and other basic OpenGL functions, but are they just simply replacement or are there other requirements? I am still not that great with OpenGL and mainly rely on GLUT, I don't know how well GLSL will blend with GLUT

Answer (score 2):

GLSL is a totally different language, compiled separately from your program, so **no**, you can't use it's datatypes in OpenGL. Take a look at [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) instead.

Also, please note that there doesn't exist any equivalent of `glVertex3f` in GLSL; GLSL starts its processing at Vertex Shader stage, which is *after* you supply vertex data to the program.

Comment: so how do you use GLSL? do you have to download it? what library do you include to use it? the sample programs don't tell me where to load the GLSL library into the project

Comment: You have to load glsl code into your program and compile it using C API

Comment: if you have a graphics card and it supports decent version of OpenGL (like 2.1, or higher) then you are able to use GLSL. GLSL are only mini programs that are compiled by driver and sent to execute on the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

> how do you use GLSL?

GLSL is a completely independent language for the implementation of *shaders*. Shaders are programs that are compiled by the OpenGL implementation and executed in the OpenGL renderer. GLSL is not something you use in your host program.

For the host side of vector math there are several libraries:

- [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org)
- [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/)

Or, still very early in development

- [linmath.h](https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h)

> do you just include gl.h and get access to vec3 and cross functions?

That's not how it works.

Comment: so how do you use GLSL? do you have to download it? what library do you include to use it? the sample programs don't tell me where to load the GLSL library into the project

Comment: @TopTierTracker: "*the sample programs don't tell me where to load the GLSL library into the project*" Any [decent OpenGL tutorial](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides) will [tell you](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut01%20Making%20Shaders.html) what you need to do.

Comment: @TopTierTracker: GLSL is not a library. It's a language. You just use it. It's part of the OpenGL implementation. This is a minimal GLSL example program: https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/minimal_glsl/minimal_glsl.c – the lines 24 to 42 contain a string which implements shaders in GLSL.